# My PhD fellowship for spring semester has already been paid to me. If I drop out mid-semester, what is the likelihood that I'll have to pay it back?

Tags: funding

I understand this question has been asked before, but my question is unique in that I am paid a lump sum stipend at the beginning of each semester *for* that semester. In other words, my tuition is fully-funded, and I'm *also* awarded a 22k stipend which is deposited in the first week of each semester (11k at the beginning of the fall semester, 11k at the beginning of spring).

My question:
If I were to drop out in the *spring* semester, would it be likely that I be required to pay that 10k back for the incomplete semester?

I know this varies by state law (I'm in the US) and by specific fellowship, and I will try to find a discreet way of asking someone in the university administration, but I am wondering what the probability is of having to pay this back. The paperwork I signed had no specific information on it.

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this question without knowing the contents of your contract. Is there something like a "student handbook" with policies that apply to you? Does your paperwork reference other specific documents that contain additional terms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I drop out of a PhD program, do I have to pay back the university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148439/if-i-drop-out-of-a-phd-program-do-i-have-to-pay-back-the-university)

Comment: @AnonymousM That one is a bit different, because it addresses money from previous semesters.

Comment: @BryanKrause Sure, my feeling is this is either too dependent on individual factors or else the given dupe target is the best possible transformation of the question into something useful.

Comment: @AnonymousM Except the dupe suggests that it's pretty much unheard of that previous semester fellowships will need to be repaid. That advice does not apply generally to leaving mid-semester.

Comment: The reason for dropping out might have a bearing.

Comment: I updated the title to make it clearer what the difference from the linked question is. That said, I am not sure whether this question should be left open; seems like the only answer we can give is that it [depends on individual factors](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/).

Answer (score 5):

For students in a similar situation, this is the guidance that my institution provides:

> If a student received financial aid from the university, they should consult the Office of Student Financial Aid to determine repayment responsibilities. If students withdraw and are receiving remission of tuition, they are responsible for their entire tuition assessment.

That last point is particularly important, because your fellowship is not just covering the stipend but also your tuition, so even if you are not required to give the stipend back, you may owe previously forgiven tuition for the semester which could even exceed that stipend.

No one here can give you a probability or guess that applies to your specific situation, you need to get specific information for your specific situation, and there is likely an office at your institution responsible for figuring these things out. If you can't find a written policy for your institution, talk to them. You may be able to do so without that information getting back to your supervisor, or to get general information from them without saying who you are.